# How to get specific type of commits from some specific date to current date using JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

using JGit framework, I would like to collect a list of commits with some specific commit message e.g. commits starting with pattern "[EA-" from a range of date e.g. since 24.01.2018 to current date as in git, git log --since=2018-01-24 --until=2020-03.30 --grep=[EA-. I have tried something as below:

```
    String path = "C:/path_to_repo";
    FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
    Repository repo = repositoryBuilder.setGitDir(new File(path, ".git")).findGitDir().build();
    Git git = new Git(repo);
    ObjectId start;
    ObjectId end;
    Iterable<RevCommit> call = git.log().addRange(start, end).call();
```

Is this corrrect to do it this way ? Secondly, how can i pass right params to addRange() method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JGit's `log` command does not support filtering for date ranges and message patterns.

You will need to use a `RevWalk` to manually traverse the history. Filters can be added to limit the resulting commits. Use `CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since, until)` to restrict commits to the desired date range.

To further filter on certain messages,  or select matching messages while iterating over the commits of the `RevWalk`.

Here is an example to get you started:

```java
try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo)) {
  walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD)));
  walk.sort(RevSort.REVERSE);
  walk.setRevFilter(CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since, until));
  for(RevCommit commit : walk) {
    if (commit.getFullMessage().contains(...)) {
      // include commit in result
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can extend `RevFilter` to write a custom message filter and use `AndRevFilter` to combine this filter with the date range filter.

See also this questions about using commit filters in JGit:

- [How do I use filters in jGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993576/how-do-i-use-filters-in-jgit)
- [How to define a "In between" JGit RevFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730329/how-to-define-a-in-between-jgit-revfilter)

Comment: that was helpful but i am testing it with CommitTimeRevFilter.after(Date date) and somehow the date is not working, it always skips the commits. Without this, it works fine.

Comment: Well, looks like you have some debugging and testing ahead of you ;-) If you share a  minimal standalone example, maybe others can help.

Comment: The problem is solved. Actually i was not providing the correct range for date. I collected a list of RevCommit which matched my custom pattern. Now, i would like to get the affected files in each RevCommit. Is there any support in JGit for that ?

Comment: Yes there is, and I'm sure that has been answered already on SO or elsewhere. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Comment: why can't i use git.log().setRevFilter(CommitTimeRevFilter.between(Date since, Date until)) ? and then apply filtering on message of each RevCommit.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the `LogCommand` supports filters. However, be aware that the `LogCommand` leaks the `RevWalk` it uses internally without closing it.